# Is Pascal's Rule the only such identity?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am wondering if [Pascal's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule) is the only such identity in which

$$\binom{a}{b}+\dbinom{c}{d} = \binom{n}{m}$$

Precision aside on the expression above, in general I am wondering if there exist *non-trivial* examples where two binomial coefficients add to become another binomial coefficient. Any example with $b=1,d=1$ or $m=1$ is trivial: $$\binom ab + \binom cd = \binom{\binom ab + \binom cd}1\\\binom{a}b+\binom{\binom nm-\binom ab}1=\binom nm$$

Also, we can require $2b\le a$, $2d\le c$, and $2m\le n$ without loss of generality.

If there do exist non-trivial examples, how could one generate them?

Comment: Yes, it is effectively the only such identity involving the sum of only two binomial coefficients.  You can get special cases like the one you mention, or isolated instances like how $\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{3}=\binom{20}{1}$.  Otherwise, you have the binomial theorem or special cases of that where you stop the sum halfway or leave a term off of either end... you also have the hockeystick identity.

Comment: Hint: the RHS is asymptotic for large $n$ to $n^m/m!$; therefore, either both terms on the LHS are degree-$m$ polynomials in $n$, so $b=d=m$, or one is while the other is $o(n^m)$, so without loss of generality $a$ is linear in $n$, $b=m$ and $d<m$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I am puzzled by the discussion. There are examples without a $1$ as lowest coefficient, such as ${4 \choose 2} + {6 \choose 2} = 6+15=21={7 \choose 2}$. How can we prove that they are "isolated instances"? That would at least require limiting the kind of relation we allow between $a,b,c,d,m,n$. If everything is allowed, there is certainly a way to find formulas for those isolated instances, and they won't be isolated anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relation:

${n \choose 2} + {{n \choose 2} \choose 2} = {{n \choose 2}+1 \choose 2}$

Non trivial, but quite obvious, because ${{n \choose 2} + 1 \choose 2} - {{n \choose 2} \choose 2} = {{n \choose 2} \choose 1}$ by Pascal's relation, and ${{n \choose 2} \choose 1} = {n \choose 2}$.

This actually generalizes to:
${n \choose p} + {{n \choose p} \choose 2} = {{n \choose p}+1 \choose 2}$
because ${{n \choose p } \choose 1} = {n \choose p}$.

Note that:

- $\forall n, {a_1n+a_2 \choose p} + {b_1n+b_2 \choose q} = {c_1n+c_2 \choose r}$, to be possible when $n \to \infty$, requires $p=r$ and (wlog) $q \le p$.
- $\forall n, {a_1n+a_2 \choose p} + {b_1n+b_2 \choose p} = {c_1n+c_2  \choose p}$ is impossible as soon as $p \ge 3$, because of Fermat-Wiles on $n^p$ coefficient.

So the only left case for ${a_1n+a_2 \choose p} + {b_1n+b_2 \choose q} = {c_1n+c_2 \choose r}$ is $p=r, q<r$ (wlog, as $p$ and $q$ can be switched).
For $p=r=3, q=2$, the only solutions I find are trivial ones - notably Pascal's relation.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a computer program to find all nontrivial instances in the first twenty rows.
$$
\binom{0}{0} + \binom{6}{3} = \binom{7}{2}\qquad\binom{0}{0} + \binom{7}{3} = \binom{9}{2}\qquad\binom{0}{0} + \binom{11}{2} = \binom{8}{3}\\
\binom{4}{2} + \binom{6}{2} = \binom{7}{2}\qquad\binom{4}{2} + \binom{13}{2} = \binom{9}{3}\qquad\binom{4}{2} + \binom{10}{3} = \binom{9}{4}\\
\binom{4}{2} + \binom{16}{2} = \binom{9}{4}\qquad\binom{4}{2} + \binom{11}{3} = \binom{19}{2}\qquad\binom{5}{2} + \binom{7}{3} = \binom{10}{2}\\
\binom{5}{2} + \binom{10}{2} = \binom{11}{2}\qquad\binom{5}{2} + \binom{8}{3} = \binom{12}{2}\qquad\binom{5}{2} + \binom{9}{4} = \binom{17}{2}\\
\binom{5}{2} + \binom{10}{4} = \binom{12}{3}\qquad\binom{6}{2} + \binom{7}{2} = \binom{9}{2}\qquad\binom{6}{2} + \binom{11}{2} = \binom{8}{4}\\
\binom{6}{2} + \binom{15}{2} = \binom{10}{3}\qquad\binom{6}{3} + \binom{7}{3} = \binom{11}{2}\qquad\binom{6}{3} + \binom{9}{2} = \binom{8}{3}\\
\binom{6}{3} + \binom{20}{2} = \binom{10}{4}\qquad\binom{7}{2} + \binom{10}{2} = \binom{12}{2}\qquad\binom{7}{2} + \binom{8}{4} = \binom{14}{2}\\
\binom{7}{2} + \binom{9}{3} = \binom{15}{2}\qquad\binom{7}{2} + \binom{15}{2} = \binom{9}{4}\qquad\binom{7}{3} + \binom{8}{3} = \binom{14}{2}\\
\binom{7}{3} + \binom{8}{4} = \binom{15}{2}\qquad\binom{7}{3} + \binom{14}{2} = \binom{9}{4}\qquad\binom{7}{3} + \binom{17}{2} = \binom{19}{2}\\
\binom{7}{3} + \binom{17}{3} = \binom{13}{4}\qquad\binom{9}{2} + \binom{11}{2} = \binom{14}{2}\qquad\binom{10}{2} + \binom{14}{2} = \binom{17}{2}\\
\binom{10}{2} + \binom{16}{2} = \binom{11}{3}\qquad\binom{10}{2} + \binom{9}{4} = \binom{19}{2}\qquad\binom{10}{2} + \binom{11}{3} = \binom{10}{4}\\
\binom{10}{2} + \binom{12}{6} = \binom{19}{3}\qquad\binom{12}{2} + \binom{8}{4} = \binom{17}{2}\qquad\binom{12}{2} + \binom{15}{2} = \binom{19}{2}\\
\binom{8}{4} + \binom{10}{3} = \binom{20}{2}\qquad\binom{8}{4} + \binom{16}{2} = \binom{20}{2}\qquad\binom{13}{2} + \binom{10}{5} = \binom{11}{4}\\
\binom{13}{2} + \binom{13}{5} = \binom{15}{4}\qquad\binom{9}{3} + \binom{17}{2} = \binom{12}{3}\qquad\binom{10}{3} + \binom{16}{3} = \binom{17}{3}\\
\binom{16}{2} + \binom{10}{4} = \binom{11}{4}\qquad\binom{13}{3} + \binom{14}{4} = \binom{13}{5}\qquad\binom{13}{3} + \binom{13}{6} = \binom{14}{5}\\
\binom{14}{3} + \binom{16}{3} = \binom{12}{6}\qquad\binom{16}{3} + \binom{16}{6} = \binom{18}{5}\qquad\binom{17}{3} + \binom{20}{3} = \binom{16}{4}\\
\binom{13}{4} + \binom{14}{4} = \binom{13}{6}\qquad\binom{15}{4} + \binom{14}{6} = \binom{16}{5}\qquad\binom{16}{4} + \binom{17}{5} = \binom{16}{6}\\
\binom{14}{5} + \binom{15}{5} = \binom{15}{6}\qquad\binom{14}{6} + \binom{15}{6} = \binom{16}{6}\qquad\binom{15}{5} + \binom{14}{7} = \binom{15}{7}\\
\binom{18}{4} + \binom{20}{5} = \binom{18}{6}\qquad\binom{14}{7} + \binom{16}{6} = \binom{16}{7}\qquad\binom{19}{5} + \binom{20}{5} = \binom{19}{6}\\
$$
My personal favorite is
$$
\binom{14}6 +\binom{15}6=\binom{16}6\\
3003 + 5005 = 8008
$$

Comment: There's also $$ {103 \choose 40} + {104 \choose 40} = {105 \choose 40} $$
and $${713 \choose 273} + {714 \choose 273} = {715 \choose 273}$$

Comment: Ah: for more, see [OEIS sequence A089508](https://oeis.org/A089508)